# ACS ACR122U Tag display on screen using Python NFC tool library

Tags: python, android, nfc, acr122

I have one NFC reader device  ACS ACR122U, I want to send data from my android phone by using the NFC NDEF application I am using three different applications: TagWriter, NDEF Tag Emulator and NFC Tools, I write simple text like my name "NAME" and put it close to the reader to display it. I run the python tagtool.py code, provided by the
https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/tagtool.html#load

When I run this code it appears like this:

```
[nfc.clf] searching for reader on path usb
[nfc.clf] using ACS ACR122U PN532v1.6 at usb:001:040
```

Seems like working fine waiting for the Tag.
Then I put the cell phone onto the reader, the following errors comes:

```
[nfc.tag.tt4] ACS ACR122U on usb:001:040 does not support fsd 256
[nfc.tag.tt4] ACS ACR122U on usb:001:040 does not support fsc 256
```

Is there anyone who knows why there is an error instead of displaying the text it shows the not supported data?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible how you are attempting to do it.

With NFC there is the concept of `Initiator` and `Target`, the initial NFC comms and control of the communication must be `Initiator` to `Target`, with the reader hardware being the `Initiator` and the `Target` being the NFC Tag.

Currently you are trying to get and `Initiator` to talk to another `Initiator` with the 2 NFC reader applications(code) you are using, which won't work.

Luckily a lot (but not all) NFC reader hardware quite often support being a `Target` as well if they are programmed correctly. This is usually known as Host Card Emulation (HCE) or there is a Peer to Peer mode as well.

Android support HCE but you usually have to write your own Android App to do this (I don't know of any off the shelf apps to do this but there are some examples on GitHub somewhere),  Android had Peer to Peer support but it was dropped in Android 10

On the Python side there is https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/beam.html for Peer to Peer and does https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/listen.html for HCE

But your chosen reader has poor NFC support for Tag emulation or Peer to Peer by the Python Code https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#functional-support

The ACR122U is capable to do a lot of this stuff with some limitations, just you will need to program it yourself at the low level.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, do you any suggestions for the NFC that have the capability to do this or any open-source application that can do this?